# Reinstall Android OS on my HTC Butterfly

Tags: rom-flashing, htc, operating-system

I accidentally wiped all the data in the internal storage of my HTC Butterfly. Due to this incident, my smartphone is unable to connect with PC. The ROM cannot be copied into phones's internal storage. Finally, I cannot recovery my phone. It is stuck in bootloader or screen flash nothing.

Problems:

1. Unable to connect phone with PC
2. Storage card does not appear its connection with PC
3. Unable to copy ROM Recovery.img into storage card
4. Unable to install Android OS on phone
5. Finally, it's stuck in bootloader

Please share your knowledge and experience as well as solution to solve this matter.   Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this you will need the android sdk, your recovery, and your rom.
First, go to [your sdk]> sdk> platform-tools. Then put your recovery in the platfotm-tools folder. Next open a terminal there (shift + right click and it will appear in right click menu (Be carful of doing it on a folder)) then connect your device to your computer, then (Drivers may be needed) type in to terminal

```
fastboot update [Your rom.zip]
```

to flash your rom
 (if it comes in a .tar then get [7-zip](http://7-zip.org) and open it). Finally use

```
fastboot flash [your recovery .img]
```

to flash your recovery, then it should boot and be fixed !